# Liferay MVC Portlet Command mvcPath is null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have the Liferay MVC portlet example `guestbook-portlet` running

where the `view.jsp` is like

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<jsp:useBean id="entries" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="request"/>
<liferay-ui:search-container>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="<%= entries %>" />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row  className="com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Entry" modelVar="entry" >
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="message" />

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="name" />
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>

<aui:button-row cssClass="guestbook-buttons">

    <portlet:renderURL var="addEntryURL">

        <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/guestbook/edit_entry.jsp"></portlet:param>

    </portlet:renderURL>

    <aui:button onClick="<%= addEntryURL.toString() %>" value="add entry"></aui:button>




</aui:button-row>
```

when I render the page I get a `null` reference in `addEntryURL`.

My `WEB-INF/src` portlet class defines the `addEntry` public method:

```
public class NewPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    public void addEntry(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
        try {

            PortletPreferences prefs = request.getPreferences();

            String[] guestbookEntries = prefs.getValues("guestbook-entries",
               new String[1]);

            ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (guestbookEntries != null) {

              entries = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(prefs.getValues(
                   "guestbook-entries", new String[1])));

            }

            String userName = ParamUtil.getString(request, "name");
            String message = ParamUtil.getString(request, "message");
            String entry = userName + "^" + message;

            entries.add(entry);

            String[] array = entries.toArray(new String[entries.size()]);

            prefs.setValues("guestbook-entries", array);

            try {

              prefs.store();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

              Logger.getLogger(NewPortlet.class.getName()).log(
                   Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            } catch (ValidatorException ex) {

              Logger.getLogger(NewPortlet.class.getName()).log(
                   Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            }

         } catch (ReadOnlyException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(NewPortlet.class.getName()).log(
               Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

         }
    } 

    @Override
    public void render (RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) 
            throws PortletException, IOException {

        PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
        String[] guestbookEntries = prefs.getValues("guestbook-entries",
                new String[1]);

        if (guestbookEntries != null) {

            List<Entry> entries = parseEntries(guestbookEntries);

            renderRequest.setAttribute("entries", entries);
        }

        super.render(renderRequest, renderResponse);

    }

    private List<Entry> parseEntries (String[] guestbookEntries) {

        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList();

        for (String entry : guestbookEntries) {
            String[] parts = entry.split("\\^", 2);
            Entry gbEntry = new Entry(parts[0], parts[1]);
            entries.add(gbEntry);
        }

        return entries;
    }

}
```

and I have the `portlet.xml` configured action like

```
<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>guestbook</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Guestbook</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.test.NewPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-template</name>
            <value>/html/guestbook/view.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
```

But as soon as  I click the button the url is `http://localhost:8080/null`

Comment: Sounds like tld file import needs to be checked.Can you check if tld is correctly on build path and if it is correctly imported?

Comment: If I understood well, you created a _render URL_ `addEntryURL` to execute the action method `addRender()`. The URL should be an action URL, no?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I guess so, I have all sources in `WEB-INF/src` so the spring models are there as well. Any suggestion for the spring models configuration?

Comment: @loretoparisi The null occurs when the taglib is not able to get resolved via tld.Check if the IDE is showing any errors in resolving tag to create render or action url tags.

Comment: @brandizzi Even I was surprised to see the same but the user is using an example from Liferay blog where the action URL is used later in the example.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal hm, curious! Do you folks can share the blog post here?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal yes this is the Guestbook example from the Liferay tutorial that I have used as starting point since it has everything in to write a complete plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue like yours.

`<aui:button onClick=...>` totally can't work eventhough it's the sample from Liferay website.
Finally, I change `<aui:button>` to normal html button and it's work.

```
<button class="btn" type="button" onClick="location.href = '<%= addEntryURL.toString() %>'">Add Entry</button>
```